# How to determine the coordinates of a specified word into PDF file using Nodejs

Tags: pdf, node.js

In my case, when the user sends their CV (pdf file), I will remove sensitive information such as email, phone number. I tried placing a photo to cover it but the information is still there just not visible but still click (I can still click on the email in pdf file despite being covered by a photo).
Is there a way to actually delete that information?
Thanks a lot!

Comment: You are looking for a feature that is commonly called "redaction", and yes it is definitely possible to actually redact content from a PDF so the content is not there. What are your requirements/restrictions for the software you can use? OS? FOSS? Commercial?

Comment: Ryan is absolutely correct.  PDFs often store information people think is deleted, and it *is* possible to correctly redact that information.  Some software does it well, whereas other software fails miserably.  I recommend always verifying results with a hex editor until you have confidence in a particular program.  Even then, I recommend random spot-checks to verify the software continues to work correctly as new versions of the program and new versions of the PDF format are released.